# Use recursion to find the 1st occurrence of a target number in an array

Tags: c, arrays, search, recursion

The code can alr return the position of the target number. However, it is also given that the program should return -1 if the target number is not in an array. It is also required that I'm supposed to use recursion only.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rLookupAr(int ar[], int n, int target);

int main() {
    int a[80];
    int target, i, size;

    printf("Enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    printf("Enter target number: ");
    scanf("%d", &target);
    printf("rLookupAr(): %d", rLookupAr(a, size, target));
    return 0;
}

int rLookupAr(int ar[], int n, int target) {
    /* write your code here */
    if (ar[0] == target) {
        if (n == 0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    } else
        return 1 + rLookupAr(ar + 1, n - 1, target);
}
```

Comment: You should definitely move the `if (n == 0)` check *before* the dereference of `ar`. You'll also want to check the return value of the recursive call for `-1`.

Comment: What's the question? Why isn't your code working?

Comment: @Charlie If the target number is not in the array, then rLookupAr() will return –1. <-- I cannot get this part.

Comment: In the future if you don't want to get down voted please write out a full example without the stdin. Homework questions are OK but please respect the communities time by making the problem easy to understand and explain what you've tried on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function can look like

```
int rLookupAr( const int ar[], int n, int target )
{
    if ( n < 1 )
    {        
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( ar[0] == target )
    {
        return 0;
    }        
    else
    {        
        int i = rLookupAr( ar + 1, n - 1, target );
        return i == - 1 ? i : i + 1;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive function cannot work as posted:

If the target number is not in the array, the index returned will be `-1`, but unless the array is empty, this return value will be offset by all the recursive calls and the final return value will be the length of the array - 1, incorrectly pointing to the last array entry.

You should modify your code this way:

```
int rLookupAr(int ar[], int n, int target) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return -1;
    if (ar[0] == target)
        return 0;
    int res = rLookupAr(ar + 1, n - 1, target);
    if (res < 0)
        return res;
    else
        return res + 1;
}
```

Note that this recursion is quite inefficient and will cause a stack overflow if the array is sufficiently large and the target sufficiently far or not present.

An alternative that still uses recursion but with limited depth will split the array and recurse on each half:

```
int rLookupAr(int ar[], int n, int target) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return -1;
    int m = n / 2;
    if (ar[m] == target)
        return m;
    int res = rLookupAr(ar, m, target);
    if (res >= 0)
        return res;
    res = rLookupAr(ar + m + 1, n - m - 1, target);
    if (res >= 0)
        return res + m + 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int rLookupAr(int *ar, int n, int target)
{
    if (n == 0) return -1;
    if (ar[0] == target) return 0;

    int _ret = rLookupAr(ar + 1, n - 1, target);

    if(_ret != -1) return ++_ret;
    else           return -1;
}
```

I see that Vlad had already suggested it, so...
see it in action: https://ideone.com/LhovTh

Answer (score 0):

```
int targ_pos( const int *p, int n, int target)
{
  if(*p == target){return 1;}

  if(n == 1){return -1;}

  return targ_pos(p+1, --n, target);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid your code does not compile: `n <= p` compares a pointer with an integer... if the target is not in the array, you would continue scanning for it beyond the end if the array.

Comment: My bad :( , it's corected.

Comment: Your function does not return the index of the target in the array, it can only return `1` or `-1`.